# How to "feel bad" for someone in Japanese

Tags: words

I suppose that the English phrase is very general but in Japanese how do you express that you feel bad for others? (something similar to pity but not particularly looking down on the person)

Answer (score 1):

同情する is the first thing that comes to mind, but it might have a bit too much of a pitying nuance.

Perhaps something like 気の毒に思う would be a good fit?